# How to obtain URL for item in absolute links-for loop (requests_html)

Tags: python-requests

I try to include the url of the currently scraped item to the dataframe

Like i scrape the title with r.html.find(...)

Is there a way to do this with requests html?

Comment: I would use BeautifulSoup

Answer (score 0):

to get the URL, obtain the element and then do `<element>.attrs['href']` to get the URL of the object

Example

```py
from requests_html import HTMLSession
session = HTMLSession()
r = session.get('https://python.org/')

about = r.html.find('.button', first = True)
print(about.attrs['href'])
```